# Unable to show Bitmap images in Grid view via C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid on aspx page

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvmails" runat="server"></asp:GridView></div>
```

and want to bind it from `List<ContactDetail>`

Here is the `ContactDetail` class

```
public class ContactDetail
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress1 { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress2 { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public System.Drawing.Image Pic { get; set; }  
}
```

On a button click I want to bind this grid. All the things are displaying correctly in Grid except pic.
Here is the my serverside code

```
public static List<ContactDetail> GetGmailContacts(string App_Name, string Uname, string UPassword)
    {

        RequestSettings rs = new RequestSettings(App_Name, Uname, UPassword);
        rs.AutoPaging = true;
        ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(rs);
        Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();
        List<ContactDetail> contactDetails = new List<ContactDetail>();

        foreach (Contact entry in f.Entries)
        {
            ContactDetail contact = new ContactDetail
            {
                Name = entry.Name.FullName,
                EmailAddress1 = entry.Emails.Count >= 1 ? entry.Emails[0].Address : "",
                EmailAddress2 = entry.Emails.Count >= 2 ? entry.Emails[1].Address : "",
                Phone = entry.Phonenumbers.Count >= 1 ? entry.Phonenumbers[0].Value : "",
                Details = entry.Content,
                Pic = GetPic(cr, entry)
            };

            contactDetails.Add(contact);
        }

        return contactDetails;

    }

    private static System.Drawing.Image GetPic(ContactsRequest cr, Contact entry)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Name.FullName))
            {
                return System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(cr.Service.Query(entry.PhotoUri));  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<ContactDetail> ds = GetGmailContacts("MyNetwork Web Application!", txtgmailusername.Text, txtpassword.Text);

        gvmails.DataSource = ds;

        gvmails.DataBind();
    }
```

Even last column pic is not coming up. Please let me know where I am missing something to show the images in grid view.

Comment: How well do you know HTML? Are you approaching ASP.NET from a WinForms or WPF perspective?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot render images directly into HTML[1]. Web-pages generally consist of multiple resources, and images are included with the `<img src="" />` element, where the `src=""` attribute specifies the resource path to the image. As you're serving images dynamically it means you'll need a separate handler for the images. You can do this with an `.ashx` file.

I'm afraid my WebForms is a bit rusty (as I vastly prefer ASP.NET MVC) but change your GridView's ViewModel to provide a URI to the image instead of the bitmap data (which you're forgetting to `.Dispose()` of, by the way), you'll then need to provide a custom `TemplateField` which writes `<img src=` to the response body.

After that, you'll need to implement the `.ashx` handler for the images themselves.

[1] Yes, you technically can with `data:` URIs, but they're intended for small images like icons, not large content like photos.